# How to stop caching of particular div using wp rocket cache plugin?

Tags: wordpress, caching, cache-control

How to stop caching of particular **div** using **wp rocket** cache plugin?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge it is not possible to STOP cache for specific DIV or SPAN etc.

In order to disable page caching, you can just install and activate this helper plugin: [using this plugin.](https://github.com/wp-media/wp-rocket-helpers/raw/master/cache/wp-rocket-no-cache/wp-rocket-no-cache.zip)
Ref. https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/61-disable-page-caching

OR use this method --> Excluding a Page From Cache via **DONOTCACHEPAGE**
 - [Exclude files and Page from cache](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/141-overriding-donotcachepage-constant-via-filter#excluding-a-page-from-cache-via-donotcachepage)

Also you can clear cache for any specific PAGE OR POST by following way.

Clear cache on specific post/page
There are two ways of clearing cache on specific posts/pages.

Visit the Pages or Posts section in WordPress, and roll over a page or post table row to see a Clear this cache action  link

[image]

Another way to do this is in on the post or page Edit screen. In the Editor panel, the Clear cache button can be found in the Publish meta box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically clear the cache of a page you can use [rocket_clean_post()](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/93-rocketcleanpost) along with the post/page id.

In cases where you have updated a **div** (or any other element) with an AJAX call you should clear the cache with `rocket_clean_post($post_id)`, so that user sees the updated div if he refreshes the page. Otherwise, if you don't clear cache and user visits the post again he will see the old, cached content.

This function has minimal impact on your website's performance because it only clears that particular post/page that has changed. Common use cases are when a user adds a comment, a "like", a vote, a review or any other AJAX powered interactions on a post/page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I decided to create this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-no-cache/. You can use it with whatever caching plugin, including WPRocket.

I hope it helps those who have the same problem.